# Hide a taxonomy term

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

How can I hide, disable or un-publish some term in a taxonomy? The term should not be displayed in published nodes.

There is the module [Taxonomy Term Status](https://www.drupal.org/project/termstatus) for Drupal 7. Maybe there is something similar for Drupal 8 as well.

Comment: Yes, it will be, in Drupal 8.6 this is in core, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2985366

Comment: Thanks. Drupal 8.6 should be released on September 5, 2018, see drupal.org/core/roadmap. I hope we can wait with the feature.

Comment: I have updated my site to the Drupal core 8.6.0-beta2. But I can not find any status field or another possibility to unpublish a taxonomy term. When performing the 'drush -y updb' I've got: 'Performing taxonomy_update_8601  [ok]'

Comment: I don't know what the plans are for taxonomy, the node entity sets `->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);` for the published field. You can do this in a hook_entity_base_field_info_alter() if you don't want to wait.